# When do new members get sworn in as congress people?

Tags: congress, parliamentary-procedure

I have seen two sources (one was LA Times) state that new members are not sworn in until *after* a speaker is elected. If that is correct, how do the results of an election get reflected in that key election?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ch. 34 of [House Practice: A Guide to the Rules, Precedents and Procedures of the House](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GPO-HPRACTICE-108/html/GPO-HPRACTICE-108-35.htm) explains that "The general practice for election of Speaker begins with nominations from each party caucus followed by a viva voce vote of the Members-elect". We know who those people are; one of these days, they may make the transition to being "Members", after the Speaker is chosen and sworn in.

[2 USC 25](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/2/25) says that after elections,

> the oath of office shall be administered by any Member of the House of
> Representatives to the Speaker; and by the Speaker to all the Members
> and Delegates present, and to the Clerk, previous to entering on any
> other business; and to the Members and Delegates who afterward appear,
> previous to their taking their seats.

It is up to the House to decide if "and" means "and after that".

Comment: So non-members vote. It solves the paradox.